# Execute RubyEval in sublime looks nothing happened

Tags: sublimetext2

macos 10.9.5
sublime version is 2.0.2

[SublimeRubyEval](https://github.com/jugyo/SublimeRubyEval/commit/cf302e6c3717155b1e3208af4692c93bbb4273f1) not works for me.

execute RubyEval in sublime looks nothing happend.

check console find out (ctrl + `):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 362, in run_
File "./RubyEval.py", line 69, in run
File "./RubyEval.py", line 50, in eval_as_ruby
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. works for me.
https://github.com/jugyo/SublimeRubyEval/pull/8

BTW: Use [jugyo / SublimeRubyEval](https://github.com/jugyo/SublimeRubyEval) is easiest way to genrate some text (like repeat html) in the sublime edit view. Other things like SublimeREPL those are too heavy to do that.